# Error on module page for Solspace's Importer

Tags: solspace

I am running into a problem with Solspace's Importer module. I haven't used it for a while and now that I went to load it up, I get the following error message just going to the module page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct() [<a href='datetimezone.--construct'>datetimezone.--construct</a>]: Unknown or bad timezone ()' in /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/addon_builder/addon_builder.php:4097 Stack trace: #0 /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/addon_builder/addon_builder.php(4097): DateTimeZone->__construct('') #1 /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/act.importer.php(65): Addon_builder_importer->timezone_offset() #2 /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/addon_builder/addon_builder.php(702): Importer_actions->__construct() #3 /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/mcp.importer.php(139): Addon_builder_importer->actions() #4 /ho in /XXX/expressionengine/third_party/importer/addon_builder/addon_builder.php on line 4097
```

I haven't made any changes to the installation since I last used it, though I can't swear to whether the host has changed anything about php since then.

Comment: What version of Importer and EE are you using?

Comment: Oh, sorry! 2.7.0

Comment: And what version of Importer?

Comment: Importer 2.2.2. I see now I had missed that there's 2.2.3 that works for my version too, so will attempt the update.

Comment: Updated and now it does work. Sorry about not checking that first.